# Forecasting Validation

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, validation

question on validating forecast models.  The traditional approach (https://otexts.com/fpp2/forecasting-on-training-and-test-sets.html) is to hold-out n number of samples from the end of your time series, and then run the model to predict those n time periods (multi-step forecast on the test set).  (let's say I have 100 daily data points, and I hold out 10 days at the end)

Doing this - and lets say I've fit an ARIMAX model for the sake of argument - I get very poor results between the actual values held out and those predicted for the holdout period.

However, if instead during the 10-day validation period I re-build the model 1-day at a time and predict 1 day ahead, I get very good results when compared to the actual values.  What is the difference - except computational effort?  I should clarify here that I don't mean re-estimate the parameters - I mean fit the model to 91 days, and predict the next day, then 92 days, and predict the next day, and so on...

The goal of the model is to predict 1-day into the future anyway, so I'm confused about why we don't just re-build the model stepwise during the hold-out period instead of trying to predict all 10-days at a time.

I'm adding some Python code to help explain:

```
n = 10  #number of days in hold-out periods
v_actu = y[-n:].reset_index(drop=True)  # the actual y values
v_preds = [] #empt array to hold 1-step ahead predictions
y2ci = [] # empty array to hold 1-step conf. intvs.

m1 = pmd.ARIMA(order=(1,1,2), seasonal_order=(1,1,0,5))
for i, elem in enumerate(v_actu):
    m1_fit = m1.fit(y[:-(n-i)], exogenous=x_vars_all[:-(n-i)], suppress_warnings=True, stepwise=True)
    y2_pred = m1_fit.predict(n_periods=1, exogenous = pd.DataFrame(x_vars_all[-n:].reset_index(drop=True).loc[i]).T, return_conf_int=True)
    v_preds.append(y2_pred[0])
    y2ci.append(y2_pred[1])
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for this "traditional approach"? I think you have it backwards (i.e. your suggestion is actually the standard way of assessing 1-step-ahead performance).

Comment: actually, I think you are quite right.  https://otexts.com/fpp2/forecasting-on-training-and-test-sets.html.  I think I actually just did not understand what I was reading.  I had been holding out n samples, and then trying to predict forward n samples without re-building the model at each step (so set the horizon to 10, for instance).  He actually says to rebuild the model at each step.  such a rookie mistaker!   No wonder nothing ever worked...  (insert face palm)

Comment: in Hyndman's first example on the link I sent (Multi-step Forecasts on Training Data), it seems he is suggesting my initial approach above.  Hold-out 60 days of data, then apply the fitted model and forecast out the entire 60 days.  Later on in the page he discusses the one-step at a time approach.

Comment: How do you plan to use this model? For example, if the goal is near future planning for training and staffing your customer support center in the next year, the second approach seems good. If the goal is long-term planning (say you are deciding to build a factory and need a forecast of demand for a few years to determine if you can recoup your investment), the first approach seems more sensible. Being able to adjust you forecast might still be useful as time rolls forward for operational reasons, but you need to know how good your model is X years out at the moment of the building decision.

Comment: it's daily data, I'm planning to forecast the "sales" for tomorrow.  (this is all hypothetical, of course)